# De Morgan's laws in logic and set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, soft-question

In logic De Morgan's law means $\lnot (A \land B) \Leftrightarrow \lnot A \lor \lnot B$

In set theory De Morgan's law means $(A \cap B)^C = A^C \cup B^C$

I'm surprised that the same idea is true in different fields. Is there any explanation for this phenomenon or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: Not a coincidence. It is essentially the same equation.

Comment: If you let $\Omega$ be the set of states of the world, and identify each proposition with the states that make that proposition true, then you have a bijection between sets and propositions.  The bijection takes $\vee$ to $\cup$, $\wedge$ to $\cap$, and $\neg$ to complement; so de Morgan's laws *must* be the same.

Comment: @mjqxxxx, the magic word that you haven't used is "isomorphism".

Comment: @mjqxxxx, I don't get what that means: "identify each proposition with the states that make that proposition true"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The explanation can be seen in the following chain of equivalences: $$\begin{align}(A \cap B)^C & = \{x\mid x \notin (A \cap B)\}\\ \\ & = \{x\mid \lnot [x\in (A\cap B)]\} \\ \\& = \{x\mid \lnot (x \in A \land x \in B)\} \\ \\ & = \{x\mid \lnot(x \in A)\lor \lnot (x \in B)\}  \\\\& = \{x \mid x \notin A \lor x \notin B\}\\ \\ & = \{x\mid x\in A^C \lor x \in B^C\} \\ \\ &= A^C \cup B^C\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't think the OP asked for a proof, @amWhy ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm showing that DeMorgans among sets is nothing more or less that DeMorgans applied to propositions. So it is not surprising that there is a correspondence, which is also reflected in Martial's answer.

Comment: @amWhy, you replaced $\cap$ with $\land$ in the second line. Why is it correct?

Comment: I missed that, @amWhy...+1

Comment: @Yaldc  See my edit. I jumped ahead of myself too quickly. Then $x \in (A\cap B) = x \in A \land x \in B$, by the definition of set intersection.

Comment: @amWhy, thank you very much. After rereading your answer, I realized that actually I know this proof. But it has never occurred to me that the proof represents "intersection" of logic and set theory.

Comment: You're welcome, Yal dc. There's much more to that intersection: E.g. $\subseteq \iff \rightarrow$: $$A\subseteq B\;\text{ means }\;x \in A \rightarrow x \in B$$ just as conjunction correlates with set intersection, and disjunction correlates with set union.

Answer (score -1):

My opinion is that set theory law is just a special case of the logic law. For example, we can note $a\in A$(in set domain) as $\mathcal{A}$(in logic domain) and $a\notin A$ noted as $\lnot\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Downvoted because if set theory is a special case of the logic law, you must show why or at least sufficient evidence to convince the reader